# how do i change a variable in an others class that will change its value in all class in java

Tags: java, class, variables

Having the following two classes:

**class1**

```java
int a = 10;

public void Main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(a);   // will print "10"
    class2 c2 = new class2();
    class2.ChangeValue(a);
    System.out.println(a);   // will print "10" even after the value has
                             // been set to 20 in the other class
}
```

**class2**

```java
public void ChangeValue(int a){
    a = 20;
    System.out.println(a)    // will print "20"
}
```

the question is, how do I make this value be 20 in all classes and not just the class that changed it.

Comment: you are printing a in class 1 and changing a in class 2. The two a fields, although named the same, area completely different. You can make it static.

Answer (score 0):

Make that value static, or simply use singleton pattern.

Comment: I would guess your downvote is for suggesting using a singleton model. It's not something to be suggested lightly. Your recommendation of `static` is however the correct one.

Comment: Yes it might be that, I don't know why someone have downwoted it, thats life. I don't think that my answer is qualified for downwote.

Comment: Using a `public static` (or package-visible `static`) field that is shared between more than one class is _worse_ than having a singleton, from a design standpoint.

Comment: I know. What from my suggestion is.

Answer (score 0):

In the implementation of `class2`, you must declare the variable being changed by  `class2.ChangeValue(a);` as `static`.

A static class variable exists once per all classes. All other class variables will exist within each instance of the class.

If you want coordination between classes, you're going to have to do that yourself in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a static in class two and access it that way.

Class 2:

```
static int a = 10;

public void ChangeValue(){
    a = 20;
    System.out.println(a); //will print "20"
}
```

Class 1:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(Class2.a); //will print "10"
    Class2 c2 = new Class2();
    c2.ChangeValue(Class2.a);
    System.out.println(Class2.a); //will print "10" even after the value has been set to 20 in
                           // the other class
}
```

or the other way around

Class 1:

```
static int a = 10;
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(a); //will print "10"
    Class2 c2 = new Class2();
    c2.ChangeValue(a);
    System.out.println(a); //will print "10" even after the value has been set to 20 in
                           // the other class
}
```

Class 2:

```
public void ChangeValue(){
    Class1.a = 20;
    System.out.println(Class1.a); //will print "20"
}
```

The suggestion to use Objects instead of primitive types would also work. This way you could pass the object as a parameter and the value would carry over.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a primitive data type int to pass to another method and changing its value. Primitives are always passed by value. So you will always lose its value changed in other method. Two ways to mitigate:

1. Use objects which will be passed by reference
2. Make int a as static and than change its value in another method like {class1.a =20}

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but it's impossible, because they are in the different scope, the "a" you put into class 2 is a formal parameter and temporary, when the ChangeValue is finished, the "a" is gone, they are totally in a different world.

PS: you should use uppercase on class, like Class1, Class2, and lowercase on method, changeValue.